# Why are lab Magnets painted red?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, magnetic-fields, history

Wy are lab magnets painted red in color?
I tried searching everywhere but couldn't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is about physics!

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it just a convention ? And are all the laboratory magnets around the worle painted red ?

I would agree with you that mostly they are painted red as i once bought a lot of laboratory bar magnets made of AlNiCo all of them were painted red while same was not true when I bought some higher power loadstone magnets they were simply in their original state (no paints and blackish) electromagnets are not painted at all as well. Some extremely good permanent magnets I don't remember what they were made of, but they were round and very powerful were finished in silver.

Maybe it is a convention which makes nearly all the permanent lab magnets red, but I can assure you that not all of them are red.

Comment: Are you thinking of neodymium magnets?

Comment: Yes these were the ones.

PS : no offence but the question is about red color and your user name is reds just kind of fits in. LOL

Comment: @rijulgupta, please have a look at your spellings in the answer!

Comment: @shortstheory : I am using the site from a mobile, I am sorry if not all the spellings are correct.

Comment: Haha, please have a look when you get back to a physical keyboard.

Comment: Dont smear salt on the blood wound, that is the pathetic touchscreen keyboard.

Comment: I think neodymium magnets have chromium coating, not silver.

Answer (score -5):

**Probably because magnets have a negative charge, and the customary colour for negative charges is red**

Comment: Magnets normally are not charged.